# Spherical Harmonic Expansion On Non Unit Sphere

Tags: spherical-harmonics

Is there a way of expanding a scalar field defined on a sphere of radius R in the base of spherical harmonic functions? Everywhere I read about expansions on the unit sphere. What changes if one would try this for a function on a sphere of arbitrary radius?

Edit: (I want to precise my question)
The particular problem I am dealing with is numerical and as follows:

I have two functions $f(\theta, \phi)$ and $g(\theta, \phi)$, they are both defined on a sphere of radius R.
I would like to compute the convolution $f *g$ of these two functions.
If I they are expanded in the a series of spherical harmonic functions I can use the following convolution theorem:

$\hat{(f*g)}_{l,m} = \sqrt{\frac{4 \pi}{2l+1}} \hat{f}_{l,m} . \hat{g}_{l,0}$

As far as I understood the expansion and the convolution theorem only work for functions on the unit sphere. Is there any way I use this method for a sphere of radius R?

Edit2:
Numerically the functions are defined on a $\theta$-$\phi$-grid. So my idea was to compute the coefficients $a_{l,m}$, then convolve in the spherical harmonic space and then expand to be in normal space again.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)$ is defined over a sphere of radius R, then $f(Rx)$ is defined over the unit sphere. Try expanding this scalar field first, and then scale appropriately.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. I modified my question to be more precise. Maybe you could give me a little more input. What do you mean with scale appropriately?